# R - Rasterize a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame - variables/attributes dropped

Tags: r, spatial, r-raster

Whenever I rasterize my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, I lose the attribute / data information part. The command "rasterize" is from the package "raster" in R.

I have the following RasterLayer (named "raster1")

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 6000, 4800, 28800000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.00025, 0.00015  (x, y)
extent      : 8.699875, 9.899875, 46.69993, 47.59993  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:3857 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
```

My SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (named "bw1") has the following properties

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 7663 
extent      : 980075.6, 1076577, 5908811, 6023151  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:3857 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs 
variables   : 2
names       :    A,  B 
min values  : 3231, 11 
max values  : 3955, 19
```

When I use a the command

```
bw1_raster<-rasterize(bw1,raster1,fun='last',field=c("A","B")
```

I get the new object "bw1_raster":

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 6000, 4800, 28800000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.00025, 0.00015  (x, y)
extent      : 8.699875, 9.899875, 46.69993, 47.59993  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:3857 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 
+lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       : layer     
values      : NA, NA  (min, max)
```

How do I get a raster object with attributes / layers "A" and "B"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the coordinate reference system of the SpatialPolygons do not match that of the RasterLayer. It *looks* like they match, but that is probably because you changed the crs of the RasterLayer to an incorrect value. The RasterLayer almost certainly has a  longlat crs, not merc.

You need to assign it the correct crs (or at least do not change it to a wrong one!).

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could use spTransform to transfrom the *SpatialPolygons* to the crs of the RasterLayer and try again.

Alternatively, you could do something along these lines

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(bw1, res=10000)
r <- rasterize(bw1, r)
```